# Change chmod from /sbin/shutdown

Tags: terminal, permission, shutdown

I'd like to change the rights of the shutdown executable from 751 to 750, because I'd like non-admin users to have no right to shutdown their Macs. Except I have the `chmod error: Unable to change file mode on shutdown: Operation not permitted.`

Is it possible to change that? If not, do you have a solution to block users to shut down the Mac?

*The command chmod is run as root

Comment: It is blocked by SIP and (if Catalina) read-only file system. Which macOS version(s) do you have?  Even if you work around that, what about the power button?

Comment: The permissions of shutdown are set to 755 (not 751) and effectively to (500). Only the super-user can execute the command (either sudo'ed or su'ed or as root). So what's your problem here?

Comment: +1 
I hate it when I am not root on my system...
I consider writing a kernel extension...